# Header menu title spacing off in grid

Tags: html, css

Hope you are all doing great.

I have this code, the header menu sort of work but for some reasons the space between each title is off, I quite tried everything, align-center,self,content , justify-content ... but nothing seems to work, where I am failing ?

I have no idea if it's either Home or Contacts that spacing is completely off

thank you for helping

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@500&display=swap');

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a, u {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "main"
    "footer";
}

.page-header {
  grid-area: header;
  height: 12.5vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
}

.grid-header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px);
  grid-template-rows: 2.5em;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

#ph-home {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

#ph-blog {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

#ph-contacts {
  grid-column: 3/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

#ph-home>a, #ph-blog>a, #ph-contacts>a {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 120%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/home.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <header class="page-header">
      <ul class="grid-header">
        <li id="ph-home">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li id="ph-blog">
          <a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li id="ph-contacts">
          <a href="#">Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to increase the width of Grid columns: https://nimb.ws/CxZF0Q Right now 50px is not enough.

Comment: I know but it was to really showcase the issue, if you take a closer look at 100px it's off

Comment: Yes. Don't use a fixed width column then. Use padding or margin. Flexbox with `space-evenly` would help too.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, I should not use grid for headers or any elements that needs to have a certain flow ?

Comment: You can use Grid. But change the `justify-content: center;` to `justify-content: space-evenly;` Centering it would center the entire 3 columns with the width you provided,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify your columns and rows in fractions and force them to take up that percentage of the width of their parents along with `grid-template-areas: "#ph-home #ph-blog #ph-contacts"` and `grid-area` on the children. Then add a `display: flex` on the children of the grid to give them a justify-content property.  This will ensure everything is spaced out nicely with no need to add a gap statically in pixels.

**On your grid parent:**

```css
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "#ph-home #ph-blog #ph-contacts";
```

**On your grids children:**

```css
#ph-home {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-area: #ph-home;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@500&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a,
u {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "footer";
}

.page-header {
  grid-area: header;
  height: 12.5vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
}

.grid-header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "#ph-home #ph-blog #ph-contacts";
}

#ph-home {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-area: #ph-home;
}

#ph-blog {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-area: #ph-blog;
}

#ph-contacts {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-area: #ph-contacts;
}

#ph-home>a,
#ph-blog>a,
#ph-contacts>a {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 120%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/home.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <header class="page-header">
      <ul class="grid-header">
        <li id="ph-home">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li id="ph-blog">
          <a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li id="ph-contacts">
          <a href="#">Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the 'header'

```
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping, since I'm using grid is there a reason why I have to switch to flex ? I'm just trying to understand (But yeah, your right it's working)